# Как можно изменить цвет подсветки выбранного в списке элемента?

Tags: python, tkinter

Мною создан список типа 'Listbox', при выборе в нём элемента. он подсвечивается синим цветом, насколько я понял - это настройка по умолчанию. Я хочу поменять цвет подсветки на другой, например жёлтый. Как я могу это сделать? Вот кусок кода:

```
list_0 = Listbox(frame_0, font='Arial 13', selectmode=SINGLE, height=3, width=30)
for d in list_0_data:
    list_0.insert(END, d)
```

Подскажите, какой параметр надо изменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать команду `selectbackground = "Ваш цвет"`

```py
list_0 = Listbox(highlightcolor = "yellow", frame_0, font='Arial 13', selectmode=SINGLE, height=3, width=30, selectbackground = "black")
for d in list_0_data:
    list_0.insert(END, d)
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли)))